# AngularJS - unchanged data passed by ng-model is interpreted as undefined instead of the value

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular to generate some `input`s and populate them with data using `ng-repeat`. I also want to bind the data inside the `input` to a `save changes` button which takes parameters provided by `ng-model` directives. `save changes` button prints the passed arguments using the built-in JS `arguments` object. For some reason, **unless** I change the text inside the `input` box, the output is `[undefined, undefined]`. Once I change the text inside the `input` boxes, the correct output is printed. Why is that?

[JSfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/3xhe1x5p/).

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p ng-repeat = "man in men">
      <label>name</label><input type="text" ng-model="mname" ng-value="man.name"><br>
      <label>status</label><input type="text" ng-model="mstatus" ng-value="man.status"><br>
      <button ng-click="save(mname,mstatus)">
      save changes
      </button>
  </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.men = [{
    name: "jon snow",
    status: "depands"
  }, {
    name: "rob stark",
    status: "dead"
  }];
  $scope.save = function() {
    console.log(arguments);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not **recommended** but for your specific requirement you can use `ng-init` to bind `ng-value` to your model

```
  <p ng-repeat = "man in men">
      <label>name</label><input type="text" ng-model="mname" ng-value="man.name" ng-init="mname = man.name"><br>
      <label>status</label><input type="text" ng-model="mstatus" ng-value="man.status" ng-init="mstatus = man.status"><br>
      <button ng-click="save(mname,mstatus)">
      save changes
      </button>
  </p>
```

This wouldn't bind your changes to the original model.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/3xhe1x5p/1/)

Answer (score 1):

ngModel doesn't update untill you use a key to change it, or set it from your controller. Because you are setting the field of the input using ngValue, it doesn't register to your ngModel untill you change it.

This problem is similar to how most datepickers don't work with ngModel, as they set the field with DOM-manipulation and NOT by inserting the value by "key".

You can easily fix this by using the following HTML instead:

```
<label>name</label><input type="text" ng-model="man.name"><br>
<label>status</label><input type="text" ng-model="man.status"><br>
```

I simply removed the ngValue and linked the ngModel to your "man".

Comment: This will bind the model to the input field. Which is not the requirement here I guess.

Comment: I dont fully understand what are the consequences of binding the model to the input? I need two things, first is to add the data to the input using ng-repeat and second is to pass the data inside the input to a function.

Comment: If you bind the input to ngModel, the values will not simply be shown by the input, but also actually changed in your JS. For more information on this, look up Two-Way binding.

The two things your are trying to achieve are achieved by this method, but there may be side-effects depending on what the rest of your application must do.